# How to remove newline items from a list in Python?

Tags: python, string

I'm creating a list from an e-mail body and the output list contains thousands of `'\n'` and `'\t'` characters. I would like to know how to remove them from a Python list.

**NOTE: I'm expecting to remove only the items that have no other values, since there are some index in the list that contains valuable information and special characters at the end I don't want to remove them. For example: `[..., '\n', 'WDO\n', '\t\t\n', ...]`**

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) 
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetFirst()

for msg in messages:
    subject = msg.Subject
    if (subject.find('ABCDEFG') != -1):
        assunto = subject
        conteudo = msg.body
        File_object = open(r"C:\Projetos\E-mail\body.txt","w")
        File_object.write(msg.body)
        File_object.close() 
        break

File_object = open(r"C:\Projetos\E-mail\body.txt","r")
lista = File_object.readlines()
```

And this is the output of the list:

```
lista[0:16]

['Segue dados de hoje. \n',
 '\n',
 '\n',
 '\n',
 ' \n',
 '\n',
 '\n',
 '\n',
 'WDO\n',
 '\n',
 '\n',
 '\n',
 '\t\t\n',
 '\n',
 'Média\n',
 '\n']
```

Comment: Can you post expected output too? I'm assuming you only want a list of `Segue dados de hoje.`, `WDO`, and `Média`

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `isspace` to determine if the list element is just whitespace, eg, tab, newline, etc.

```
[x for x in lista if not x.isspace()]
```

Output:

```
['Segue dados de hoje. \n', 'WDO\n', 'Média\n']
```

---

If you also want to remove the newline character and other white space at the end, use `rstrip`:

```
[x.rstrip() for x in lista if not x.isspace()]
```

Comment: This is very elegant and much better than using regex

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: `x.strip()` for leading & trailing whitespace

Answer (score 1):

`listb = [x for x in lista if (x.strip() != "")]`

Comment: OP wants to remove `'     \n'` as well, while your code would only filter out `'\n'`

Comment: You are correct, updated.